# PHP/FORM - Is there any way to POST html code from <div> into mysql with php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I've recently created a bracket, which should be postable in order to collect people votes. The form consists of 4 elements:

1) bracket (html code with jquery dynamic actions),

2) name,

3) e-mail address,

4) submit button.

Posting name/mail within form is easy with those input tags, but is there any way to also post a bracket along with the actions that player has taken on it?
Would be grateful for any help!

**EDIT:**

I've made as follows:

**form in html,**

**jQuery script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        var formData = {
            'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'formularz'    : $('#formdiv').val()
        };

  $.ajax({
      type        : 'POST', 
      url         : 'process.php',
      data        : formData,
      dataType    : 'json',
      encode          : true
  })

  .done(function(data) {

     console.log(data); 

  });

  event.preventDefault();
                    });

});
```

**process.php:**

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = '---';
$db_pwd = '---';
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd);  
$database = '---';

if (!mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Brak połączenia z bazą danych.");

if (!mysqli_select_db($con, $database))
    die("Nie można wybrać bazy danych.");

function sql_safe($s)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $s = stripslashes($s);
    global $con;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $s);
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{   
    $name = trim(sql_safe($_POST['name']));
    $email = trim(sql_safe($_POST['email']));
    $formularz = trim(sql_safe($_POST['formularz']));

    if ($name == '')
        $msg = 'Wpisz swoje imie.';
    if ($email == '')
        $msg = 'Wpisz swoj email';
    else
    {
        if (!isset($msg))
        {
                $safeform = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $formularz);

                $resultform = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM votedata WHERE email='$email'");
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultform) == 0) {
                        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO votedata (name, email, safeform) VALUES ('$name','$email','$safeform')");
                    }
                    else {
                        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE votedata SET name = '$name', safeform = '$safeform' WHERE email='$email'");
                    }
                $msg = 'Formularz został wysłany, dziekujemy!';
            }
        }
        elseif (isset($_GET['email']))
            $msg = 'Błąd - nie mozna wyslac formualarza';
}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Seems like ajax is flawless, but i still won't get tables updated/inserted into after sending form...

Comment: yes try with the ajax

Comment: u mean to construct whole form sending operator with ajax right?

Comment: yes but you can also do it for only your bracket(on click action) call ajax request

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: i'll try ajax approach, let you know here if ill manage to make it work :D

Comment: edited Qquestion

Answer (score 0):

Just off the tip of my head, I see 2 options here:

- Send the data via an Ajax POST request
- Add an equal number of "hidden" input fields for each div whose code you want posted, which should be updated via JS on every change made in their respective div(s) (and make sure you name them accordingly, as their value will be the data submitted in the end, and not the divs' data)

Comment: Yeah, the second option u gave also passed my head but it seems like pretty confusing way to do this. I'll give ajax a try, will keep updated here :)